# What is the pros and cons of react native uses primitives and flutter create all elements and control every pixel

Tags: react-native, flutter

I know that react native convert the element to their primitives in ios and android.

for example Button converts to UIButton in IOS and Widget.Button in Android.

but flutter control every pixel in the app and not convert elements to their primitives.

So what is the pros and cons of using primitives?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used React Native, but I've heard many horror stories about being able to get the same "look and feel" across platforms, and even working around bugs in same.
Flutter builds the widgets from pixels, and doesn't seem to have that same issue.